# Cognos CAST within a CASE

Tags: sql, case, cognos-10

I thought I was going to do something simple but it's giving me errors.  I am trying to combine our order# with the order suffix which I can do without a problem use a CAST statement. I need the result to be order#-## (123456-01).  The issue arises when there are more than nine releases and I get 123456-010 as I have added a '-0' in my combine.  I've tried this but it gives me parsing errors:

```
CASE WHEN [Order Suffix] > 9
THEN CAST (([Order #],varchar(7)) + '-' + CAST ([Order Suffix],varchar(2)) 
ELSE CAST (([Order #],varchar(7)) + '-0' + CAST ([Order Suffix],varchar(2))
END
```

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to accomplish this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what do the parsing errors say is the problem?

Comment: This is difficult to analyze without the error message.  And what data type is [Order Suffix]?

Comment: int32 (Integer)

Comment: Your original post mentions "parsing errors".  I still don't see the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CAST()` uses the syntax `as <type>` is basically all databases (this is a standard function.

Perhaps this will do what you want:

```
 (CAST(([Order #] as varchar(7)) +
  (CASE WHEN [Order Suffix] <= 9 THEN '-0' ELSE '-' END) +
  CAST([Order Suffix] as varchar(2))
 )
```

Notice that this factors out the common code in the two expressions.  I think that helps with maintainability.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  I get this error when applying that code:
QE-DEF-0459 CCLException
QE-DEF-0260 Parsing error before or near position: 20 of: "(CAST(([Order #] as varchar(7)) +
  (CASE WHEN [Order Suffix] <= 9 THEN '-0' ELSE '-' END) +
  CAST([Order Suffix] as varchar(2))
 )

Comment: Change "as" to a comma.  It's Cognos, not SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I've changed the as to a comma and still get the following:
QE-DEF-0459 CCLException
QE-DEF-0260 Parsing error before or near position: 18 of:  "(CAST(([Order #],"
QE-DEF-0261 QFWP - Parsing text:  (CAST(([Order #], varchar(7)) +
  (CASE WHEN [Order Suffix] <= 9 THEN '-0' ELSE '-' END) +
  CAST([Order Suffix], varchar(2))
 )

Comment: Ok.  Got it working.  Ended up with with one-sided nested parenthesis. Got the same number on both sides, a comma in place and code works perfect!  Thanks for putting up with me guys!

CAST([Order #], varchar(7)) + (CASE WHEN [Order Suffix] <= 9 THEN '-0' ELSE '-' END) +  CAST([Order Suffix], varchar(2))